# Array of objects, difference between Java and C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I am new to C++ and I am porting over a Java project to C++.

Consider the following Java code, where Piece is a class representing a chess piece:

```
Piece[][] myPieces = new Piece[8][8];
```

It creates an array where all the entries are null.

How can I achieve the same thing in C++? I tried:

```
Piece* myPieces = new Piece[8][8];
```

But this will create an array with all the entries initialized with the default constructor.

Thanks

**Edit:** I want the C++ code to be efficient/elegant and I do not care nor wnant to copy paste from Java to C++. I am happy to heavily modify the code structure if needed.

**Edit 2:** The code is for chess programm, the size of the array will **never** change and performance is critical.

Comment: Not a wise thinking if compare two different languages.

Comment: Agreed. Don´t try to press Java 1:1 into a different language.

Comment: If the comparison to Java bothers you, just think of it as "How can I have a 2D array of optional objects in C++?" I think the answer will sufficiently convince the asker that C++ and Java should be treated in different ways.

Comment: In C++, if you want your vector to be 2D, then you need to define it as such. Either use `Piece** myPieces = new Piece*[8];`, iterate over all 8 elements and create for each a new vector of 8 elements (ergo 64 total elements), or use a 1D vector and use indirect indexing..

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know java used to let you allocate arrays of  objects without calling their constructors

Comment: @MarcoA. In Java you do not create an array of _objects_, you create an array of _references_. This is the same distinction as for variables. Their values are references but not objects.

Comment: @Daniel That is a terrible way to create a 2d array!

Comment: +1 for wanting to find out the best C++ way instead of copying Java.

Comment: @NeilKirk The 2D one or the 1D with indirect indexing one? Would you mind clarifying why? I'm also mostly Java-oriented with a basic/medium C++ knowledge, so explaining would help

Comment: @Daniel See my answer for how to create a fixed-size 2d array in C++.

Comment: @JosephMansfield: Now if you would explain why that is the best translation to C++? Keep in mind that the result should be good C++ and only have as much resemblance as proper expression of the problem (Model a chess-board, and the pieces on it) naturally leads to.

Comment: You may find this question useful as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405074/differences-between-the-c-and-the-java-object-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends, because contrary to Java, in C++ you have different ownership semantics and object lifetime management (the two go hand in hand).

If you want to model objects similar to java, you would write:

```
using PiecePtr = std::shared_ptr<Piece>;
std::array<std::array<PiecePtr, 8>, 8> Pieces;
```

The shared_ptr has similar semantics to a java object (pass it around wherever and it's lifetime is guaranteed as long as there are references to it).

If you want to model observed objects (i.e. the array doesn't own them), you should write:

```
using PiecePtr = Piece*;
std::array<std::array<PiecePtr, 8>, 8> Pieces;
```

This ensures that when the `Pieces` object gets destroyed, the actual pieces themselves remain in memory.

If you want to model unique objects, owned by the `Pieces` array, you should use:

```
using PiecePtr = std::unique_ptr<Piece>;
std::array<std::array<PiecePtr, 8>, 8> Pieces;
```

This ensures that when the Pieces object gets destroyed, the actual pieces themselves get destroyed as well.

Comment: Fails on performant and on good C++ for that situation: Polymorphism is severe overkill and not good for performance.

Comment: @Deduplicator, what polymorphism? std::array is not polymorphic, neither are std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr (I'm not sure what you are refering to).

Comment: You are using pointers to `Piece`s, and there is no reason to use them unless `Piece` is polymorphic or optional. And considering the OPs constraints on a solution, polymorphism is out and a non-existing `Piece` should be modeled by a placeholder-`Piece`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, ah, ok. When you mentioned polymorphic I thought "virtual functions" not "pointers". Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @utnapistim What is the difference between the 3 cases you explained and: std::array<std::array<Piece, 8>, 8>.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to declare an 8x8 array of optional objects in C++ is like so:

```
boost::optional<Piece> myPieces[8][8];
```

The  `boost::optional` type represents an optional object (like your nullable references in Java) that doesn't have all the pitfalls of using pointer types. It should be available as part of the standard library in the next few years.

You may prefer to use the `std::array` type, which is an encapsulation of fixed-size arrays that allows them to be treated as first-class citizens and also provides a nicer interface:

```
std::array<std::array<boost::optional<Piece>, 8>, 8> myPieces;
```

If you want to be able to resize your arrays at run-time, consider `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Java 8 finally has `Optional<>` too. Nice about `array` too.

Comment: Does boost::optional have any negative impact on performance?

Comment: @Romain: Yes, because `boost::optional<Piece>` is naturally bigger than `Piece` itself.

Answer (score 5):

As you want it performant, and right for C++ instead of a dumb translation, how about this:

Use a size-1 POD-type for piece.
Add all the convenience-methods you might want to it:

```
struct Piece {
    unsigned char value;
    constexpr Piece() : value() {}
    constexpr operator bool() const {return !value;}
    constexpr bool empty() const {return *this;};
    constexpr bool black() const {return value&0x80;}
    constexpr bool white() const {return value && !black();}
    constexpr unsigned piece() const {return value & 0x7f;}
};
```

Now that would be an equivalent raw array:

```
Piece board[8][8];
```

Or use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
std::array<std::array<Piece, 8>, 8> board;
```

Comment: You are missing const on your methods and I don't understand how the empty function works.

Comment: @NeilKirk: Added, also `constexpr` while I was at it.

Comment: Ah, that one is: Convert `*this` to `bool`, which means use `operator bool`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Can you explain a bit more about the empty() method? I still don't really understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: The empty method is just returning the object itself (*this). Because the return-type is bool, that implies conversion to bool, which means the custom cast is used. That custom operator bool() just returns `!value`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you'd do something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Pieces>>> myPieces;
```

Comment: Fails on "good C++" for that situation, also on "performant".

Comment: This is not "the same thing in C++". This is an array of _variable length_ and _owned_ pointers. Java doesn't have owned pointers at all (only shared).

Answer (score 2):

Semantically equivalent would be:

```
Piece* myPieces[8][8]
```

as java only knows objects on the heap, pointers.

As Piece probably is not a final class, but has King, Queen, this is the way to go.

Comment: -1: Nope, it won't compile in C++ (arrays can't have their size not specified). Anyway, this is a poor approach in C++.

Comment: @milleniumbug: added 8s; I was more concerned with the type, the pointer, as I think using a pointer is relevant here. What about inheritance? Or do you mean with poor approach using a matrix? Thanks.

Comment: Removed -1 since the my main complaint was fixed. However, IMHO this use of inheritance seems forced, since there are only several kinds of chess pieces. (storing different types requires pointer/smart pointer usage and is quite intrusive)

Comment: @milleniumbug Yes there is now already an answer with `shared_ptr` from utnapistim. In fact I was one of the first to use std, so now as Java programmer I love to see `Piece*` to be deprecated in the C++ community. About inheritance: in java typical used here, but sometimes I dream of an inheritanceless programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In c++, newly created object (even in array) is created with default constructor. That's one of the important differences with java. If you want to call constructors individually, just use vector of vectors and add each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with java but I believe from what I got that this could be a good replacement in C++:

```
std::array<std::array<unique_ptr<foo>, 8>, 8> arr = {};

if(arr[2][3].get() == nullptr) // Can check for null elements
    std::cout << "this is null";

arr[3][4].reset(new foo()); // Initialize an element
```

- smart pointer avoids memory leaks
- [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) provides performances comparable to a normal C array
- [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) provides each pointer a null value
- fixed size as the java array

Comment: Yes, and that's probably less ugly to see. Sometimes I'm definitely contrived, sorry :P

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make a Chess engine and performance is critical. There are several online tutorials for this. Speed is important for a Chess AI so it can consider more moves per second, but you may need to sacrifice elegance for that.

You can either store the piece values in the board array directly, or store the pieces in a separate backing array and create the board as pointers to these pieces. There are some advantages to the second approach which I can't remember right now.

```
std::array<std::array<Peice *, 8>, 8> Board;
std::array<Piece, 32> Pieces;
```

You can represent an empty cell as a null pointer.

If you want everything in the same array, you can simply use

```
std::array<std::array<Peice, 8>, 8> Board;
```

But you will need to create a "dummy" piece value to represent an empty cell.

Note there is no dynamic memory allocation and the data is compact in memory so better cache performance.

Piece could be an enum or a struct with some useful getter functions, such as IsWhite.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you have to declare as:

```
Piece *** myPieces;
```

then, allocate as:

```
myPieces = new Piece **[8];
```

then,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  myPieces[i] = new Piece *; 
}
```

Now, if you do,

```
myPieces[0][0] = new Piece(); // C++, calls default constructor of Piece
```

In Java,

```
Piece[][] myPieces; 
myPieces = new Piece[8][8];
```

now, if you do,

```
myPieces[0][0] = new Piece(); // Java, calls default constructor of Piece
```

Since you have 8x8 known already, you may also declare as (in C++):

```
Piece * myPieces[8][8]; // 64 pointers preallocated as 8 rows, 8 cols
```

then,

Now, if you do,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    myPieces[i][j] = new Piece(); // or new Pawn or new Knight etc, subclass of Piece
}}
```

or allocate as needed e.g.

```
myPieces[0][0] = new Piece(); // or new Pawn or new Knight etc, subclass of Piece
```

Comment: Why not at least use vectors? Also speed is important and indirect 2d arrays have poor cache performance.

Comment: I just answered the question, didn't improve upon, vector usage will provide definite abstraction, but that wouldn't hep to know the difference of Java reference and C++ pointer, So...

Comment: This is the way to go, the majority of other answers are just horribly verbose and inefficient. Also, as the OP stated, the board has fixed size so you might consider something like 'Piece *myPieces[8][8]'.

Comment: @XDnl Huh?? This is a very verbose and inefficient solution. You even suggest a different and more efficient solution in your same comment.

Comment: -1: Horrible, horrible C++ approach. C++'s `new` is discouraged (exception unsafety, memory leaks, verbosity), and with 41 dynamic allocations, it's also inefficient, since none of the allocations are actually required since the size is known at compile time.

Comment: edited my ans with optimizations in allocations for 8x8 board (earlier one was generic with any board size)