# The switch from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, jakarta-ee, programming-languages

I am a C++ developer through and through. I am passionate about the language, and in particular really enjoy the power that template meta-programming and compile-time polymorphism gives me, and the more recent developments such as C++11's variadic templates and rvalue references etc.

I like that C++ gives me so much control, and the ability to do neat tricks with memory to eek out performance improvements.

I have recently been offered the opportunity to interview with a company which does all its dev in Java. They claim they are passionate about technology first and foremost, and that they are struggling to find really good technologists. As such are looking to take on hardcore C++ technologists and have them do the swap over to Java.

Knowing very little about Java, I am unsure as to whether this is a path I want to go down.

- Are the low-level nuts and bolts available to us in C++ taken away in Java?
- Will a passionate C++ developer enjoy Java or long to go back to C++?

I realise this is very subjective, but I'm hoping someone who has walked this path before can offer some insight.

Comment: I'm C++ developer and now I port megabytes of source code to Android... It looks like I'm already in HELL! BTW, it's difficult to compare these two so different things like C++ and Java, of course I'm missing C++ and I want to finish my monkey job asap, but also I have to admit that few things in Java is good for me. As for me C++ is much more flexible and convinient tool for development, but Java is much easier for newbie.

Comment: You wont get any of the fun stuff, that's for sure. No more pointer arithmetics, no more `Segmentation fault`, no more stupid semantics that make your code a mess. Just that silly JVM and all of it's prim and pretty libraries. No, I don't think you'll be very happy.

Comment: FWIW, people doing C++ still do assembler from time to time: same difference.

Answer (score 6):

Look at these threads -

[What is the difference between Java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387256/what-is-the-difference-between-java-and-c)

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/thinkinginjava/comparingc++andjava.html

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-JAVA-Differences-Between-JAVA-And-C-CPP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

http://www.csun.edu/~hbcsc240/C++vsJava_St.htm

[What is the main difference in object creation between Java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820178/what-is-the-main-difference-in-object-creation-between-java-and-c)

If anyone has better threads they should edit my answer.